# Problem in fitting the excel cell size to the size of the content when using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am beginner to Apache POI api.  I am trying to create  excel sheet using arraylist.

My java code is as follows.

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
     HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
        style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

    HSSFRow row4 = sheet.createRow(4);
    row4.createCell(4).setCellValue("name");
    row4.createCell(5).setCellValue("emailId");
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);
    List<Bean> nameList = this.getArrayList();

    Iterator<Bean> nameListIterator = nameList.iterator();


    sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);

    int i=5;
    HSSFRow row = null;


    while(nameListIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Bean bean = nameListIterator.next();

        row = sheet.createRow(i);
        row.createCell(4).setCellValue(bean.getName());


        row.createCell(5).setCellValue(bean.getMailId());
        i++;
    }
```

The arraylist is as follows:

```
List<Bean> beanList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
    beanList.add(new Bean("Amy","g@y.comrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyr"));
    beanList.add(new Bean("Joan","p@y.comrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyr"));
    beanList.add(new Bean("Megan","r@y.comrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyr"));
    beanList.add(new Bean("Joe","m@y.comrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyr"));
    beanList.add(new Bean("Febi","j@y.comrtyrtyrtyrtyrtyr"));
```

When the excel sheet is generated, the column does not fit to the size of the content correctly.  I searched Google related to this problem and found

sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);

is the solution to my problem.  I added as in the code above, but still the problem persists.  Am I using it correctly?

Is there any other solution?

Please help

Thanks in advance

P.s: I am using Apache Poi 3.6

Comment: you are setting the auto column size before the data is being written. Therefore it doesn't know how to size it. Add it after your loop

Comment: @Sean  Very useful explanation for a beginner like me.  Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190317/apache-poi-excel-big-auto-column-width

Comment: @gavenkoa How is the link you provided relevant to the discussion in this page?

Comment: @mvg It provides same answer as for your question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You just need to move the call to

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(5);
```

to a point in your code *after* the data has been added, so right after your while loop should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your answer solves me the problem.  I just moved the autosizecolumn call after the while loop and it works now.  Thanks again.