# Apache POI Excel - how to configure columns to be expanded?

Tags: java, excel, expand, apache-poi

I am using `Apache POI API` to generate `excel spreadsheet` to output some data.

The problem I am facing is when the spreadsheet is created and opened, columns are not expanded so that some long text like Date formatted text is not showing up on first glance.

I could just double click the column border in excel to expand or drag the border to adjust the column width but there could be 20+ columns and there is no way I want to do that manually every time I open the spreadsheet :(

I found out (though could be wrong method) `groupRow()` and `setColumnGroupCollapsed()` might be able to do the trick but no luck. Maybe I'm using it in wrong way.

**Sample Code snippet**

```
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        //create sheet
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("masatoSheet");

        //not really working yet.... :(
        //set group for expand/collapse
        //sheet.groupRow(0, 10); //just random fromRow toRow argument values...
        //sheet.setColumnGroupCollapsed(0, true);

        //create row
        Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        //put a cell in the row and store long text data
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Loooooooong text not to show up first");
```

**When this spreadsheet is created, the "Looooooong text not to show up first" string is in the cell but since the column is not expanded only "Loooooooo" is showing up.**

How can I configure it so that when I open my spreadsheet, the column is already expanded???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190317/apache-poi-excel-big-auto-column-width

Comment: You seem to be looking for a way to use POI to accomplish this. But to do it simply in Excel select the entire sheet and double click the A-B column heading boundary. If you need to do this to several sheets a coded solution may serve you better.

Comment: Check out my answer in other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73571342/13227834

Answer (score 220, accepted):

**After** you have added all your data to the sheet, you can call `autoSizeColumn(int column)` on your sheet to autofit the columns to the proper size

Here is a link to the [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#autoSizeColumn-int-).

See this post for more reference
[Problem in fitting the excel cell size to the size of the content when using apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015623/problem-in-fitting-the-excel-cell-size-to-the-size-of-the-content-when-using-apac)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that `autoSizeColumn` does not scale well and will be *super* slow if you have lots of rows. I had to get a little hacky and do something similar to what was suggested [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983203/how-to-speed-up-autosizing-columns-in-apache-poi).

Comment: **Warning about** *autoSizeColumn*, this requires java Font be available. This is not part of the headless java jre used on servers and will throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: The best way we found was to loop over each row in the col, find the longest char length and multiply by x + add a buffer. X use trial and error to see what fits but it should be a average width of a char. Without font I don't believe you can actually get it right but we get pretty close. Otherwise you can add a macro to excel to fix it all the first time the user opens it, that was the best method but requires macros be enabled

Comment: As others pointed out in comments, autoSizeColumn works, but it slows down A LOT, I used it in my project and the difference was about 3 seconds on 10 rows, imagine having hunders - thousands of rows

Comment: It works but it is too slow. Check my answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73571342/13227834

Answer (score 55):

**Tip :** To make Auto size work , the call to `sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnNumber)` should be made **after** populating the data into the excel.

Calling the method before populating the data, will have no effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069820/android-poi-crash-when-using-autosizecolumn sometimes that not working

Comment: The answer provided here is related to Java, whereas the link provided in the comment is related to Android. The answer still works in all Java cases (except for headless java JREs which don't have the java Font available).

Comment: thanks, I calculated func, and used setColumnWidth in the following way:                                                         
                                                               
   
                                                              

   `(5 until row.lastCellNum).forEach { colNum ->
            val columnWidth = (row.getCell(colNum).toString().length * 0.44 + 2.24) * 768
            reportSheet.setColumnWidth(colNum, columnWidth.toInt())
        } `

Answer (score 55):

If you want to auto size all columns in a workbook, here is a method that might be useful:

```
public void autoSizeColumns(Workbook workbook) {
    int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        if (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum());
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting `NullPointerException` at `row.cellIterator()`. Is it because i have no value in one of the cell?

Comment: Have you tried to create a more general solution? Because the current one doesn't seem to work well with merged regions. I mean if you use somewhere sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(...)) the approach won't work well.

Answer (score 11):

You can try something like this:

```
HSSFSheet summarySheet = wb.createSheet();
summarySheet.setColumnWidth(short column, short width);
```

Here params are:column number in sheet and its width
But,the units of width are pretty small, you can try 4000 for example.

Comment: Good to know thanks! I think for my purpose where the column string might get generated dynamically, auto-sizing method would fit in the case.

Answer (score 9):

For Excel POI:

```
sheetName.autoSizeColumn(cellnum);
```

Comment: It works, but it is very slow. The better way it to calculate column width and use setColumnWidth().

Answer (score 9):

If you know the count of your columns (f.e. it's equal to a collection list). You can simply use this one liner to adjust all columns of one sheet (if you use at least java 8):

```
IntStream.range(0, columnCount).forEach(sheet::autoSizeColumn)
```

Comment: A few years old, but when you're at it, make it shorter by using the method reference: `IntStream.range(0, columnCount).forEach(sheet::autoSizeColumn)`

Comment: @BAERUS thanks! i have adjusted it to use your suggested shorter variant

Answer (score 7):

sample code below

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("your sheet name");
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);

cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("A BIG NAME WITH AUTO SIZE FEATURE ENABLED");
```

//this is crucial

```
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
```

//argument must be cell number

```
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("a big name without auto size feature enabled");
```

Check the output and go nuts :)

Comment: sheet.setColumnWidth(columnIndex, width) is also a method you wanna have a look at

Answer (score 4):

You can add this, after your loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i<53;i++) {
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use below simple solution:

This is your workbook and sheet:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("YOUR Workshhet");
```

then add data to your sheet with columns and rows. Once done with adding data to sheet write following code to `autoSizeColumn` width.

```
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 15; columnIndex++) {
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);
                }
```

Here, instead 15, you add the number of columns in your sheet.

Hope someone helps this.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the text as well. PFB sample code:

```
CellStyle wrapCellStyle = new_workbook.createCellStyle();
                    wrapCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, use this one line code
dataSheet.autoSizeColumn(0)

or give the number of column in bracket
dataSheet.autoSizeColumn(cell number )

Answer (score 0):

you can use resize column sheet.autoSizeColumn but dont use it each time use it when you done writing

Answer (score -1):

You can use `setColumnWidth()` if you want to expand your cell more.