# Consistent column widths with Sheet.autoSizeColumn(n)

Tags: apache-poi

I'm having a bit of trouble with Sheet.autoSizeColumn.

Using the same data

1. if I use Excel's built in Format/Column/AutoFit Selection feature, I get a column width of 1.07"
2. if I use Poi on my dev box, I get a column width of 1.25"
3. if I use Poi in my target environment, I get a column width of 0.96"

What do I have to control to get consistent sizing in different environments?

Comment: Do you have the correct font installed everywhere? The sizing is very dependent on how big each letter is, and that depends on the font being available to check with

Comment: I have the same problem - **Different column width on different environments (dev, test, prod) when I use autoSizeColumn feature**. I use exactly same Java version everywhere. Also, I set Serif font (which is supported in JVM by default) as default font for each cell (blank or filled in). Nothing helped. Do you have any update/solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the column with "hardcoded" like this:

```
sheet.setColumnWidth(short column, short width);
```

[Apache POI Excel - how to configure columns to be expanded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611018/apache-poi-excel-how-to-configure-columns-to-be-expanded)