# Generate column width in excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using javabridge with php to create excel file using poi (org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook class)

To set column width for default font (Arial 10) i calculate max length and use formula

strlen($string) * 256 that works fine

Since the first row is BOLD i have to change formula. A part of the title is hidden when this column has the max length.

Do I have to replace 256 by other value ?

I will use Arial 10 everywhere to make it easier

Comment: In apache-poi, can't use access the column's `.EntireColumn.AutoFit` property?

Comment: I found a link. see if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611018/apache-poi-excel-how-to-configure-columns-to-be-expanded) is what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use the built-in [Sheet.autosizeColumn method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29) ?

Comment: yes ! cause after downloading the latest 3.10-beta2, call to $sheet->autoSizeColumn hangs web server and i have to stop / start apache.


This method didn't exist in the release i used before that comes with javabridge

Comment: may be the answer here .. didn't try it .. too long to post

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200801.mbox/%3C7814987.521200446599084.JavaMail.SYSTEM@sm2%3E

Comment: and may be here 

http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/HSSFSheet-autoSizeColumn-method-doesn-t-work-properly-on-Linux-system-td4270552.html


it needs .ttf files that are not included in jre or jdk under solaris and i cannot find them