# apache poi excel big auto column width

Tags: java, apache-poi, out-of-memory, big-o

I am try to create a big excel 2010  with 30 columns and 1 million records with Apache poi latest. I am creating as describe in this link http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BigGridDemo.java  . but I want column width to be same as column header text size. but when I am doing this after creating excel with following code

```
for (int x = 0; x < sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); x++) {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(x, 20*256);
        }
```

it is taking a huge time and even with 5gb heap size I am getting out of memory.

thanks

ram

Comment: Why aren't you using SXSSF? That's the new replacement for the demo BigGrid stuff

Comment: yes, seen SXSSF will use in future project ..... come to know later

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First Select the first row or header because only Header can give you the max number of cells in a row.

```
HSSFRow row = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0);
```

Then use `autoSizeColumn` on each column of that row

```
for(int colNum = 0; colNum<row.getLastCellNum();colNum++)   
    wb.getSheetAt(0).autoSizeColumn(colNum);
```

This will set the column width same as that of its Header width.

Comment: Sometimes not works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069820/android-poi-crash-when-using-autosizecolumn

Comment: giving Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext; –

Comment: @RameshBhati check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37070120/624003

Answer (score 5):

I would also suggest you look at using sxssf. It uses an xml format to load it into Excel. This is much faster and a better way to create large reports or grids. The autosizing function in xssf takes too long by default.

Answer (score 4):

`sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnNumber)` works.
This will resize the column to the largest cell length.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37069820/android-poi-crash-when-using-autosizecolumn - sometimes not works

Comment: giving Error:     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;